# Displaying an array of objects extending a jlabel

Tags: java, object, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I am trying to display an array of objects extending jlabel on a jpanel. I know  that the objects are there and overlapping themselves. I tried using : content.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10)); content being the jpanel but the objects are not displaying correctly.

Does anyone have a suggestion to my problem? I'm sure it's a stupid mistake but I can't seem to find it =/.

Thank you in advance.

```
public class Vue extends JFrame{
JButton start, stop, pause;
JPanel content;
Case tabC;
Case tabLab[][]= new Case[10][10];
Mouton m = new Mouton(2, 3, 'm');
Vue(){
    this.setTitle("Evolution");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
    start= new JButton("START");
    stop = new JButton("STOP");
    pause = new JButton("PAUSE");
    content = new JPanel();

    Herbe h =new Herbe(0, 0);
    Loup l = new Loup(0, 0, 'm');
    for(int cpt=0;cpt<10;cpt++){
        for(int cpt2=0;cpt2<10;cpt2++){
            tabLab[cpt][cpt2]=new Case(l,null,cpt,2);
            tabLab[cpt][cpt2].setSize(50,50);
            content.add(tabLab[cpt][cpt2]);
        }   
    }
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));

    menu.add(start);
    menu.add(stop);
    menu.add(pause);    


    content.setBackground(Color.gray);
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
    this.setJMenuBar(menu);
    this.add(content);
    setContentPane(content);


}
```

and this is the object extended by JLabel

```
    public Case(Object o,Object o2,int x,int y) {
    JLabel l = new JLabel();
    setIcon(new ImageIcon("loup.png"));
    ob1=o;
    ob2=o2;
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}
```

Comment: I suspect your image is not loading because `"loup.jpg"` is a relative file name.  Either use an absolute file name, or package the file in your .jar and pass the URL returned by the Class.getResource method to the ImageIcon constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I just didn't put the full code but it does extend JLabel ^^
the whole thing actually goes:

```
public class Case extends JLabel {
Object ob1;
Object ob2;
int x,y;

public Case(Object o,Object o2,int x,int y) {
    JLabel l = new JLabel("something");
    setIcon(new ImageIcon("loup.png"));
    ob1=o;
    ob2=o2;
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the proper code. This is not an answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

When you say "the objects are there and overlapping themselves" does that mean you can see them in the JPanel? Where are they in the grid? You seem to give the objects a fixed y = 2.

Comment: When you say "the objects are there and overlapping themselves" does that mean you can see them in the JPanel? Where are they in the grid? You seem to give the objects a fixed y = 2.

Comment: Your comment should be a comment on the original question, not a comment on your own not-an-answer answer.

Comment: Problem is - I*m not allowed to comment on the original question due to reputation being to low. Now my reputation has decreased as a result. Kind of a catch-22...